# Problema ao enviar arquivo com Form-Data Angular

Tags: angular, formdata

No meu projeto, tenho que enviar um arquivo pro meu backend, porém quando chego no back ele não pega os meus parâmetros, provavelmente seja um problema no meu service.

segue meu ts e service.

TS:

```js
 sendMailing() {

    this.dashboardService.sendMailing(this.mailing, this.infoUser.Id).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    });
    
  }
```

Service:

```js
sendMailing(file, id) {
    var parms = {"mailing": file, "userId": id};
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http
    .post(environment.fastzapUrl + "v1/user/mailing", parms, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
```

Comment: Olá, acrescente mais detalhes sobre o erro. Recomendo a [leitura](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta?cb=1)

Comment: Quando ele chega no back, tem duas variaveis esperando os parametros para executar, porem ele passa direto, ai eu tratei pra retornar uma msg de erro

Comment: Qual o status code retornado? Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: a mensagem foi setada por mim, retorna uma string com uma frase pro usuario, não esta dando erro no processo, o unico problema é que ele passa pelas variaveis e não guarda os parametros ai ele cai na condição que fiz e retorna a mensagem que setei pro usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o erro seja que você está setando o content-type como form-data, mas está enviando um json. Tente isso:

```js
sendMailing(file, id) {
    //var parms = {"mailing": file, "userId": id};
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("mailing", file);
    formData.append("userId", id);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http
         .post(environment.fastzapUrl + "v1/user/mailing", formData, options)
         .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
```